# tell me why this is only returning 1 result

Tags: mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM oc_category where parent_id = '253' "; // grab the category id from the parent id
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$Pid=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$sql="SELECT * FROM oc_category_description where category_id = '$Pid[category_id]' "; // grab the category name from the category id
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$Cid=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

 {
// show the results
echo '<a target="_top" href="index.php?route=product/products&product_id=' .    
$Cid['category_id'] . '"><span class="cat">' .  substr($Cid['category_id'], 0, 
50),('')  . '</span></a><br>' . '' . "\n";       
      }
```

Comment: Without your schema it is impossible to tell the reason. So plz share the schema.

Comment: I am so sorry, bu what do you mean by schema?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off doing a join - so that you only have one query. Your new query would be:

```
SELECT desc.* 
FROM oc_category cat, oc_category_description desc 
WHERE cat.parent_id = '253' 
and cat.category_id = desc.category_id
```